# input values didn't store in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Here i have create a form with login and signup.

When i run our code, it shows undefined variable in message and couldn't store user input values at the back-end.

Here is full code for your reference:

db.php:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sign-log') or die(mysqli_error($connection));
?>
```

index.php(with css):

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{          
    if($_POST['action']=="login")
    {
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
        $strSQL = mysqli_query($connection,"select name from users where email='".$email."' and password='".md5($password)."'");
        $Results = mysqli_fetch_array($strSQL);
        if(count($Results)>=1)
        {
            $message = $Results['name']." Login Sucessfully!!";
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "Invalid email or password!!";
        }        
    }
    elseif($_POST['action']=="signup")
    {
        $name       = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['name']);
        $email      = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
        $password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
        $query = "SELECT email FROM users where email='".$email."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        $numResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // Validate email address
        {
            $message =  "Invalid email address please type a valid email!!";
        }
        elseif($numResults>=1)
        {
            $message = $email." Email already exist!!";
        }
        else
        {
            mysql_query("insert into users(name,email,password) values('".$name."','".$email."','".md5($password)."')");
            $message = "Signup Sucessfully!!";
        }
    }
}


echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
input[type=text]
{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width:200px;
  min-height: 28px;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}
input[type=text]:focus
{
  width: 400px;
  border-color: #51a7e8;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 0 5px rgba(81,167,232,0.5);
  outline: none;
}
input[type=password]
{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width:200px;
  min-height: 28px;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}
input[type=password]:focus
{
  width: 400px;
  border-color: #51a7e8;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 0 5px rgba(81,167,232,0.5);
  outline: none;
}
</style>  
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <b>'.$message.'</b>
<div id="tabs" style="width: 480px;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" class="active">Signup</a></li>

  </ul>                 
  <div id="tabs-1">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <p><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"></p>
    <p><input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="login" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <form action="" method="post">
    <p><input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"></p>
    <p><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"></p>
    <p><input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="signup" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Signup" /></p>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>';
?>
```

db.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(240) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(240) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(240) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

How to store input values at the back-end and how to fix undefined variable in message.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Show the error message(s) you get

Comment: Do NOT use MD5 for passwords. It'll be a big mistake.

Comment: @JohnConde: Notice: Undefined variable: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\login-signup-in-php\index.php on line 97

Comment: why is a md5 mistake ?

Comment: @saina - you're setting `$message` inside your if statements. I'm going to guess that `if(isset($_POST['action']))` is returning false, else `$message` should be set to something.

Comment: Because it can easily be cracked.... https://crackstation.net/ @Anri

Comment: @Idris: at first, may know what is MD5?

Comment: Well you seem to be using it, so I'd assume you know it. But its a hashing algorithm. You should never store plain text passwords in a database, so you encrypt them. I'd recommend `password_hash`

Comment: @someone: can anybody explain in code?

Comment: @saina - I take it back. You're using `$message` in your code, but it's not set outside your if statements. So the first time through, `<b>'.$message.'</b>` will give you a warning - but that's before you've tried submitting the form.

Comment: @andrewsi: please help with my code, where is edit my code?

Comment: By the way, the reason nothing is stored in the database, is that you are mixing `mysql` with `mysqli`.

Comment: @jeroen: i m using mysqli..

Comment: @saina Maybe you should check your own code again.

Comment: @someone:  can anybody solve my problem?

Comment: @jeroen: I checked ..

Comment: @jeroen: I checked when i insert values, add sql query i m using mysql.. so how to fix it? can you help me out?

Comment: @saina check this for insertion in database using mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to get the point accross in a comment, so here is more complete explanation: You are mixing `mysqli_*` functions with the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. This is unrelated to the `undefined variable` warning you get.

The problem is here:

```
    else
    {
        mysql_query("insert into users(name,email,password) values('".$name."','".$email."','".md5($password)."')");
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^ not good
        $message = "Signup Sucessfully!!";
    }
```

`mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions are not exchangable like that, you could use both but then you would have to open a database connection for each.

So to solve your problem you need to do the same as in the previous query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,'insert ......');
```

Comment: I edited my code to  $result = mysqli_query($connection,"insert into users(name,email,password) values('".$name."','".$email."','".md5($password)."'"); still couldn't store in backend.

Answer (score 0):

the variable $message is inside the body of IF, initialize it before isset like this

```
$message = '';
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{.....
```